# Why will <Link> work in header but not on home page using React-Router-Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am creating a website that is using React Router. All my links are working fine in the header but when I try to create a link on my home page it will not work. There must be a step I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated!

App:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom"
import Header from './Header';
import MilesForm from "./MilesForm";
import Weather from './Weather';
import PaceCalculator from "./PaceCalculator";
import WeeklyGoal from "./WeeklyGoal";
import Home from "./Home";

const getGoal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('goal') || "[]");

const App = () => {
  const [goal, setGoal] = useState(getGoal);
  const [milesToGo, setMilesToGo] = useState();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setGoal(e.target.value)
  }
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setMilesToGo(goal)
    localStorage.setItem('goal', goal)
    window.location.reload();
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          {/* <Route path="/" element={<Home />} /> */}
          <Route path="Home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="WeeklyGoal" element={[ 
            <WeeklyGoal
              handleChange={handleChange}
              handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
              goal={goal}
            />,            
            <MilesForm
              goal={goal}
              milesToGo={milesToGo}
              setMilesToGo={setMilesToGo}
              path="./MilesForm"
            />
]} />
          <Route path="Weather" element={<Weather />} />
          <Route path="Pace" element={<PaceCalculator />} />
        </Routes>        
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Header:

```
import React from "react";
import './css/header.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState } from 'react';

const Header = () => {
    const [burger, setBurger] = useState(true)
    const handleToggle = () => {
        { burger ? setBurger(false) : setBurger(true) }
    }
    return (
        <div className="header-style">
            <h1 className="header-title">3-2run</h1>
            <button className="burger-btn" onClick={handleToggle}>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
            </button>
            <div
              className={burger === false
                ? "menu-container"
                : "hide-menu-container"
              }
            >
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="Home">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="WeeklyGoal">Track your miles</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="Weather">Weather</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="Pace">Pace Calculator</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Home: Here I have a link to the weather page that is not working. I'm confused as to why this same link will work on the header page but not on this one.

```
import React from 'react';
import './css/home.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Home = () => {

    return (


        <div className='home-container'>
            <div className='track-miles-link'>
                <h2>Track Your Miles</h2>
            </div>

            <div className='get-weather'>
                <Link to="Weather"><h2>Check Weather</h2></Link>
            </div>

            <div className='get-pace'>
                <h2>Pace Calculator</h2>
            </div>

        </div>
    )
}


export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a route with the path `/Home/Weather` so

```
<Link to="Weather"><h2>Check Weather</h2></Link>
```

won't work

You have `/Weather` route so

```
<Link to="/Weather"><h2>Check Weather</h2></Link>
```

or

```
<Link to="../Weather"><h2>Check Weather</h2></Link>
```

will work

Comment: Thak you for the quick response. I've tried your suggestions but the link still  doesn't seem to work. Do I need to change the path name in App.js?

Comment: Figure it out. I needed to change the path as you said Konrad and also I had negative Z index in my css file which I think was also affecting the link